# activerecord column type / before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

how can i massage attributes at the model level before active record converts them to the associated columns type?

my specific issue is this... a user enters an amount of money in decimal form (ie $15.32) for an integer type column called 'cents'... in my model, i try to use the before_validation hook to grab that amount and convert it to cents (should be 1532), however active record has already rounded it to an integer, and now my conversion becomes just 1500.

i can convert the amount in the params at the controller level, but i would prefer to control that in the model for the sake of staying DRY.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you don't expose your `cents` attribute at all. Use an attribute getter/setter pair called `dollars` and calculate your `cents` from that.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   …
   def dollars
     cents / 100.0
   end

   def dollars=(value)
     cents = dollars * 100
   end
   …
end
```

Comment: That's the right way to go. If you use #attr_accessible, #dollars needs to be added and #cents removed.

Comment: wonderful.  that is working great.  i never knew get & set were so simple with rails. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the before_validation hook along with the before_type_cast value.  You can do something like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_validation :convert_dollars_to_cents

   def convert_dollars_to_cents
       cents = cents_before_type_cast * 100
   end
   …
end
```

I think it is worth mentioning as many people don't know about before_type_cast values, but from an object modelling perspective some of the other suggestions here have alot to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what people are using to manage money but I have used rails_money plugin and it takes care of much of the conversions so I would first check that out.

http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/461-rails-money

But to solve your problem you want to store the money attribute as a `float` or a `decimal` on the column type.

I've seen most people do something like this.

```
t.decimal :amount, :precisions => 8, :scale => 2
```